# Java 11 HttpClient request not getting timeout

Tags: java, httpclient, java-11, java-http-client

Using java11 Http Client as below,

```java
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.newBuilder()
    .version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_1_1)
    .followRedirects(HttpClient.Redirect.NORMAL)
    .connectTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(Long.valueOf(matchMakerHttpConnectionTimeout)))
    .build();
        
HttpRequest httpRequest = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
    .POST(requestBody)
    .uri(URI.create(baseurl))
    .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(requestTimeOut))
    .setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
    .setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken).build();
        
LOGGER.info("Base url : {} with request body : {}", baseurl, request);

HttpResponse<String> response = httpClient.send(httpRequest,BodyHandlers.ofString());

LOGGER.info("Response body from delete CM API is : {}",response.body());
```

We see not receiving response from external api call happened via java 11 `HttpClient.send()` as above. Also not getting timeout as well. but timeouts are configured in HttpClient and  HttpRequest.Because the logger message after called httpclient.send() is not printed anywhere after HttpClient call happens.

Am i missing anything here? why we were not getting timeout if no response received from external call for long time?

Also why am i getting this stack trace printed more in thread dump?

```
"pool-3-thread-2" #57 prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=7204.26ms elapsed=16809.99s tid=0x000056033ed08800 nid=0x59 waiting on condition  [0x00007f263fc89000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(java.base@11.0.5/Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000c54cb950> (a java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Signaller)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(java.base@11.0.5/LockSupport.java:194)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Signaller.block(java.base@11.0.5/CompletableFuture.java:1796)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.managedBlock(java.base@11.0.5/ForkJoinPool.java:3128)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.waitingGet(java.base@11.0.5/CompletableFuture.java:1823)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(java.base@11.0.5/CompletableFuture.java:1998)
    at jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientImpl.send(java.net.http@11.0.5/HttpClientImpl.java:541)
    at jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientFacade.send(java.net.http@11.0.5/HttpClientFacade.java:119)
    at com.comcast.bo.rlcm.cmdp.helper.SampleServiceHelper.invokeAPI(SampleServiceHelper.java:273)
    at com.comcast.bo.rlcm.cmdp.helper.SampleServiceHelper.lambda$invokeCmAPI$7(SampleServiceHelper.java:220)
    at com.comcast.bo.rlcm.cmdp.helper.SampleServiceHelper$$Lambda$1778/0x0000000100d66440.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.HashMap.forEach(java.base@11.0.5/HashMap.java:1336)
    at com.comcast.bo.rlcm.cmdp.helper.SampleClassA.invokeHttpClientForExternalApi(SampleService.java:201)
    at com.comcast.bo.rlcm.cmdp.service.SampleService.lambda$processCm$4(SampleService.java:310)
    at com.comcast.bo.rlcm.cmdp.service.SampleService$$Lambda$1302/0x0000000100c6b840.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.forEach(java.base@11.0.5/ConcurrentHashMap.java:1603)
    at com.comcast.bo.rlcm.cmdp.service.SampleService.processCm(SampleService.java:224)
    at com.comcast.bo.rlcm.cmdp.service.SampleService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$f43afa24.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:687)
    at com.comcast.bo.rlcm.cmdp.service.SampleService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$33bd9b1c.processCm(<generated>)
    at com.comcast.bo.rlcm.cmdp.service.SampleService2.processCM(SampleService2.java:99)
    at com.comcast.bo.rlcm.cmdp.cmjob.processor.SampleProcessor.run(SampleProcessor.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(java.base@11.0.5/Executors.java:515)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(java.base@11.0.5/FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.base@11.0.5/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(java.base@11.0.5/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@11.0.5/Thread.java:834)
```

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but if you’re using Spring, why not use `RestTemplate` instead? It’s well documented, used more widely than Java client and simple to work with.

Comment: This could be due to https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8208693.
If you're not using `ofInputStream` to read the response you might consider using the `CompletableFuture` timeout facility as described here too https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8258397